# OG:video is not having its cached version updated on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

The page being shared is https://secure.vidyard.com/landingpage/u2x2dgXTX4U-r5j7C16kqg

Running the page through the debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.vidyard.com%2Flandingpage%2Fu2x2dgXTX4U-r5j7C16kqg
returns the proper (up to date) data for the flash player and other video information.

On an existing share on a page's wall (eg. http://www.facebook.com/RedwoodsMedia which posted the video on October 19, 2011), the embed is maintaining an older cached version with an incorrect flash player version which was update a month or two ago.

Facebook [reportedly](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo) refreshes its cache every 24 hours and running the debugger should update the cache, but I can't seem to fix this existing share. When I post the url now, it properly gets embedded, but the older shares continue to have an old version of the page.

Is there something that could be happening to block the updating of the cached version? Is there a way to fix this older embed

Comment: I've not heard of Facebook changing the old shares with the new information.  When cache updated, any future shares of that link will get the new information. Are you sure that's even documented that they will update old shares?

Comment: @DMCS We recently did a change of CDNs and from what I have seen, all existing shares were updated to reflect the change and are downloading from the new CDN. So Facebook must be updating old shares at some point. Just at least this one share hasn't been updated.

Comment: This is driving me nuts in 2015! I already changed the url in the og:video tag in a page I already posted, went to facebook debug to scratch the old one (it works there), however, when I open the video in my post, its still the old one! This is just incredible!